# How to access TextBox and label in a Nested GridView Control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am looking for a Jquery validation Script that checks the values in my textbox and displays error message in bold red. The values should be within a range like my range is between 10 and 40. If it is greater than 40 or less than 10 then the label becomes red and the message says "The value you entered is 6, it should be between 10 and 40. My textbox and labels are in the nested GridView. It should check value for each textbox. Also if the number is out of range for any textbox the save button should be disabled. and should only be enabled if all textbox values are in range.Below is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server"
    ShowHeader="False" Style="width: 100%; border-width: 0px;">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="GridView2" runat="server"
                    ShowHeader="true" GridLines="None">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the aspnet Validators, such as the `RangeValidator`

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="The value you entered is incorrect, it should be between 10 and 40" 
        ControlToValidate="txtAmount" Display="Dynamic" MinimumValue="10" MaximumValue="40"
        Type="Integer">
    </asp:RangeValidator>

    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Perhaps you have to use a `ValidationGroup`, depending on your needs.